# # Causing webview content to be cut

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

I am facing an issue where in my Android webview if there is a # character all content after said character are not displayed. I have tried encoding the already html encoded string using `HtmlEncode` of `WebUtility` to no avail. I've tried replacing all instances of the # character with its html encoded value of `&#35;` also to no avail.

The HTML is perfectly valid, I've ran it through an editor. What exactly am I missing? My code is as follows:

```
string value = "<div style=\"font-family:Helvetica; font-size: 100%\">" + programInstructionsText + "</div>";

        instructionWeb.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;
        instructionWeb.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
        instructionWeb.LoadData(value, "text/html", "utf-8");
        instructionWeb.Settings.TextZoom = 90;
```

Here `programInstructionText` is an already HTML encoded value we get from our WYSIWYG editor we have on our website.

Edit: Problem HTML is as follows, it works fine on chrome.

```
<div style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size: 100%"><p>A very long and convoluted message dealing with how to do a program correctly.</p>

<p>One thing to note is that this program WILL have # symbols. In fact I&nbsp;</p>

<p>refer to them as # in order to cause said issue. Now, that said, I am old enough</p>

<p>to remember a time when it was called the pound key. I can only imagine how confused some</p>

<p>kids are today when told to hit the pound key.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the exact HTML that is causing the problem?  Does it work if you load it in the device Chrome browser?

Comment: @Jason updated with html. Works fine on chrome browser

Comment: try encoding them as `%23`.  This is apparently a known bug - note the link is for react but if you read through it all it appears to be a Chromium issue - https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/322

Comment: @Jason yes, thank you very much. that solved it